# Unity Animation Scale Missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation

Today my tutor was helping and explaining to me how to add animations into my game, we added wobble effects to my 4 buttons. (pink, blue, yellow, purple) We fully compelted the first button together and then he left me to do the other 3 using what he had taught me. I thought I had done it correctly beause after adding the need code to all 4 of the buttons the pink button's wobble animation works, but the other 3 don't do the animation.

I was looking through to see if something was different and in the Animation dock they come up yellow and say (Missing!) even the pink button that works has this come up. I don't know what this means or how to fix it and would appreciate if anyone could help and explain this to me! Thankyou.

[image: Shows error]

```
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal"))
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                //play pink wobble animation
                m_Animator.SetTrigger("Pinkhit");
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                //play purple wobble animation
                m_Animator.SetTrigger("PurpleHit");
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical"))
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            {
                //play blue wobble animation
                m_Animator.SetTrigger("BlueHit");
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                //play yellow wobble animation
                m_Animator.SetTrigger("YellowHit");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does not seems to be issue with your code, but more likely of animation and to which object it is assigned to. If animation "says" change scale of this child object named pink button, you likely won't have pink button in your other color buttons. You may need to share more details about your animations, but my best guess would be it's an object name mismatch

Answer (score 0):

The property key frames in `AnimationClips` are **string based** on the property paths which include the type names of the component and the field names they belong to.

The `(!Missing)` can mean e.g. the following

- you removed the according `MonoBehaviour` from your object
- you renamed your according `MonoBehaviour` class
- you renamed the animated fields
- this `AnimationClip` was originally for another object and now you are trying to use it for an object which doesn't have according `MonoBehaviour` / component attached. (which basically equals the first case)
- **You renamed or changed the hierarchy structure of the according child `GameObject` which is nested under the one with the `Animator` attached**. (Renaming the root object would not be an issue)

therefore the according property paths that should be animated by your `AnimationClip` can not be found on this object.

Since the `Scale` belongs to `Transform` which is a component each and every `GameObject` has to have none of the upper points can be the case here and you most probably happened to rename the object like so:

[image]

This is of course a little bummer especially when working with prefabs, bu for the AnimationClips to work properly

- either make sure to put the `Animator` directly on the object that is supposed to be animated (in that case naming is no issue)
- or make sure you don't rename or change the hierarchy structure of according child objects

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I haven't changed any of the names of the GameObjects since I worked on it two hours earlier in class. I tried renaming them but it didn't seem to change anything. I have the same Animator on the 'Buttons' and each individual button with all of them active. What's confusing me most is that the pink button works even though it has the same yellow "Missing!" error as the others! I appreciate your response and help so far though but i'm not sure what to do as of now

Comment: Did you nest them under another object maybe? Anything alternating the property paths can cause this